# Boys, girls. Solve problem using edge-colouring.

Tags: graph-theory

In a class each boy knows precisely $d$ girls and each girl knows precisely $d $ boys.
Use a result on edge-colouring to show that the boys and girls can be paired off
in friendly pairs in at least $d$ different ways.

Please help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A theorem: In [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/165682/edge-coloring-of-bipartite-graphs), it is shown that a bipartite graph $G$ has an edge coloring with $\Delta(G)$ colors, where $\Delta(G)$ is the maximal degree of $G$.

Comment: Ok, but how to define problem in bipartite graph?
And why $\Delta (G) $ is number of DIFFERENT way?

Comment: You have boys and girls, and some boys and girls know each other (I understand that if a boy $x$ knows a girl $y$, then $y$ also knows $x$, am I right?). How would you express this as a bipartite graph?

Comment: "I understand that if a boy x knows a girl y, then y also knows x, am I right?" I understand it the same. 
And my interpretation:
http://i.imgur.com/Zs6Fm2m.jpg

@JiK, please glance: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1057889/colouring-graphs-edges

Comment: Now, what does the theorem say about the bipartite graph in your link?

Comment: Thanks, now everything become clear.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

- If you put boys on one side and girls on the other you will get a bipartite $d$-regular graph.
- By counting the edges you will get that the number of boys and girls is the same.
- Using the [Hall's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_marriage_theorem) you will get a perfect matching.
- Remove the above matching from the graph to get a $(d-1)$-regular graph.
- Repeat until you have $d$ disjoint matchings, color each using a different color.
- Use induction to formalize the above.
- There is related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/313706/26306).

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: dtldarek@ Are you from Poland :)?

Comment: @user180834 Indeed I am, how do you know?

Comment: I am also and your name is dtlDAREK :)

Comment: @Darek, could you help here? :)http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1057889/colouring-graphs-edges

Comment: Well, you are very perceptive, graph theory should't be any problem, good luck to you :-)

Comment: Sometimes it makes difficult, as you see.

Comment: @user180834 Please refrain from using non-English phrases, it is rude to others who cannot understand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19303/discussion-between-user180834-and-dtldarek).